# Nav Bar doesn't go across whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

so I am doing a challenge for FreeCodeCamp and my Nav Bar is being wonky. If you notice, it doesn't go across the entire screen so there is some white space. The only way I seem to be able to alter the dimensions of the navbar is if I get rid of overflow:hidden, but then the navbar acts really weird.

https://codepen.io/mso122591/pen/boowZv

Thanks!

HTML:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-lef: 100;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  font: bold 30px/50px Georgia, serif;
  background-color: #66ccff;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #b3e6ff;
}

.left-middle-text {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.portfolio-text {
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -1200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
}

.background-blue {
  background-color: #66ccff;
}

.background-silver {
  background-color: silver;
}

.portfolio-placeholder {
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.social-two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}

.social {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 1400px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.ptext {}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 60px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  font-size: 40px;
}

.black-box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  text-align: center;
}

dbody {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div.wrapper {
  float: left;
  /* important */
  position: relative;
  /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */
}

div.description {
  position: absolute;
  /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
  top: 0px;
  /* position will be on bottom */
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  /* styling bellow */
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
  /* transparency */
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  /* IE transparency */
}

.image-static {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="background-blue">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mike.oelbaum"><img class="social-two" alt="Facebook page. " src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-oelbaum-13253485/"><img class="social-two" alt="Linkedin page. " src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a onclick="scrollWin()">Portfolio</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="background-silver">
  <h2 style="text-align:center;"> Michael Oelbaum </h2>

  <h3 style="text-align:center"> Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer with experience in Japanese translation/interpretation
</div>
<!--Itachi background code

    -->
<div class='wrapper'>
  <!-- image -->


  <div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed;top:200px">



    <img src="https://images3.alphacoders.com/144/thumb-1920-144565.jpg" alt="Itachi Background. ">

    <h1 class="white portfolio-text"> Portfolio </h1>

    <div class='description'>

    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- description div -->

  <!-- description content -->

</div>
<h1 id=P ortfolio class="white portfolio-text"> Portfolio </h1>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
    <div class="portfolio-placeholder box">Coming Soon!</div>
  </div>



</div>

<!-- end description content -->
</div>
<!-- end description div -->
```

Comment: Bootstrap puts a left and right padding on `.container-fluid`.

Comment: @mso4491 can you combine the HTML and CSS snippets into a single snippet so that it becomes runnable?

Comment: @mso4491 Can you just use bootstrap classes at will? Why didn't you use `"fixed-top"` class in your `<nav>` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrapper `div` element called `.container-fluid` which has padding set to `15px` (the whitespace you see) on either side.  Either use a different class for this element, or add `padding: 0px !important` to your css.

Comment: Thank you!! So divs count as container fluid??

Comment: No.  You have an outermost `<div class="container-fluid">` (second line in snippet) which has this property.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the following code to the top of the css:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}
```

As long as this code is below any call to Bootstrap on a live site, you shouldn't need !important.

Comment: Thank you! It works! What is the reasoning as to why this works? Did I set something that made the navbar have padding? Does it have to do with the my div elements? I am new so being able to understand the logic as to why things fix things would be great!

Comment: This is not a good approach.  There are other elements with `.container-fluid` which would be impacted by this as well.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are saying now. By altering container fluid with css, it could affect other elements, probably divs because <div class="container-fluid"> By adding another class with padding 0px !important, I can target this problem without messing with other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Added both the `navbar` and `navbar-fixed-top` classes to the `nav` tag according to the [Bootstrap 3.3.7 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top), given it's the version you're using, and added a `margin-top: 80px` to the `background-silver` class you're using for your "subnav" element, so it won't get behind your navbar when you scroll to the top.

Also, remember to import the rest of the bootstrap dependecies to your project, aka the bootstrap theme and it's JS functions.

[Portfolio Page Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGoerP?editors=1000)

Answer (score -1):

I am not very good at css, but i believe that the `.` referse to a class ie, `.button` I would suggest using inspect element(ctrl-shift-i) to change the div you want to 100%, such as in my example :
[My rats html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvaZY.png)